# Get distinct values from one sheet of excel and copy to another sheet based on some conditions

Tags: excel, copy, distinct

I am bit new to excel programming and Stuff. I am facing some issue in a Task Can you please help

Data:

There are two sheets : Sheet1 is Input and Sheet 2 is Output.

Sheet 1 has following columns.

Item Shop Buyer Quantity in Jan Quantity in Feb

Requirement:

In my sheet if I filter by a Shop for example "Shop 1" . I get the following data

Shop Vehicle Buyer Quantity in Jan Quantity in Feb
Shop1 Car Jim 1 5 5
Shop1 Car Nick 5 6 9
Shop1 Scooter Jim 7 8 0
Shop1 Cycle Mary 9 0 0

Now I need the following :

1.Number of distinct vehicles purchased from "Shop 1" and place it in the Sheet "Distinct".
2.Sum of "Quantity in Jan" in sheet "Input" for all vehicles purchased from Shop1 and place in sheet distinct.

Following is the example values in Sheet "Distinct"

Shop    Number of Distinct Vehicles  Total Quantity in Jan
Shop1            3                          22
Shop2
Shop3

Answer (score 0):

I have not managed to work out what is where (eg is second sheet called `Sheet 2`, `Output`, or `Distinct`?, what is the order of the field names (labels)?) but maybe you can adjust to suit:

in second sheet B2 and copied down:

```
=COUNTIFS(Input!$A:$A,Distinct!A2,Input!$D:$D,">0")
```

in second sheet C2 and copied down to suit:

```
=SUM(Input!$E:$E)
```

[image: SO18676098 example]

Though you do not yet have enough reputation here to post an image you are allowed to post a link to a site (not requiring logon/password) hosting a spreadsheet example.